Looking for the name of this log-like method
In Elliptic Curve Cryptography you sometimes have to get from P to nP, say from P to 100P - the only allowed operations are adding of known quantities. So to get from P to 100P, we can of course just step up by one (P, 2P, 3P, 4P, ...,100P) or we can go faster by using previous results: P, 2P, 4P, 8P, 16P, 32P, 64P, 96P(32+64), 100P, which is 8 steps, or we could go P, 2P, 4P, 5P, 10P, 20P, 40P, 80P, 100P, which is also 8 steps.
As long as n is a power of two, a logarithm will get you the minimal number of steps.
I am looking for the name of the function/algorithm that gives you the minimal number of steps (8 in this case) and the name, if any, of the algorithm that gives you one or more of the minimal 'receipes' to get from P to nP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain

would you care to make an an answer out of this comment (the wiki page enlightened me sufficiently) @metamorphy , or should i?
